# Where are the unmarked vendors of Genshin Impact?

Tags: genshin-impact

So asides from the marked vendors in each town, there seem to be quite a few unmarked vendors in each town, in addition to vendors found just roaming the world. How many hidden vendors can I find throughout the world, and where can I find them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Mondstadt region

[image]

| # | Name | Location | Vendor Items | Stock Refresh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Shiliu | Mondstadt | Artifacts | 1 week |
| 2 | Flora | Mondstadt | Flowers | 3 days |
| 3 | Chloris | Windrise (see route) | Flowers | 3 days |
| 4 | Brook | Springvale | Food | 1 day |

---

#### Liyue region

[image]

| # | Name | Location | Vendor Items | Stock Refresh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Herbalist Gui | Liyue Harbor | Flowers/Food/Recipe | 3 days |
| 2 | Zhang Shun | Liyue Harbor | Artifacts | 1 week |
| 3 | Jifang | Liyue Harbor | Books | N/A |
| 4 | Linlang | Liyue Harbor(@Night) | Artifacts | 1 week |
| 5 | Shitou | Liyue Harbor | Mining Ores | 3 days |
| 6 | Chen the Sharp | Liyue Harbor | Food | 1 day |
| 7 | Su Er'niang | Liyue Harbor | Food | 1 day |
| 8 | Uncle Sun | Liyue Harbor | Fish/Crab | 1 day |
| 9 | Uncle Gao | Liyue Harbor | Fish | 1 day |

[image]

| # | Name | Location | Vendor Items | Stock Refresh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ms. Bai | Qingce Village | Flowers/Recipe | 3 days |
| 2 | Pops Zhou | Stone Gate | Food | 1 day |

[image]

| Name | Location | Vendor Items | Stock Refresh |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Verr Goldet | Wangshu Inn | Food/Flowers | 1 day |

Answer (score 9):

I thought unmarked vendors only sell useless items like cooking ingredients and dishes. Turns out I was wrong, they also less character upgrade mats, ores, artifacts and other useful stuff.

I've found [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/j71277/5_hidden_vendor_selling_artifacts_weapons_and/) where some vendors are reported by both OP and other commenters. I've created a list from everything from that thread with minor formatting improvements:

> 1. Artifact Vendor (Liyue)
> 2. Ore Vendor (Liyue)
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Artifact Vendor (Mondstadt)
> 4. Double Blacksmiths (Mondstadt)
>
> [image]
>
> 5. Plant Vendor (Windrise)
>
> [image]
>
> 6. Medicine Shop - Bubu Pharmacy (upper-left Liyue): sells Lotus Head for food ingredients 4* ATK, and some other Liyue specialty
> 7. Fish / Crab merchants (Liyue Harbour): Crab is one of the ingredient for 5* ATK
>
> [image]
>
> 8. Food Vendor (Liyue, literally right next to the marked food store): they sell 2 Chop suey, which decreases your climbing and sprinting stamina usage by 25%.
> 9. Flowers vendor (Qingce Village by the mill): sells Silk Flower and Glaze Lily

Answer (score 3):

Draff will also sell you raw meat and fowl if you catch him during the day in Springvale. Find him standing on a hill with Allan during the day near the houses and windmill in Springvale and you should be able to do it as long as you have completed the quest that involves him and Olaf. At night he is next to a house and won’t sell anything.

Answer (score 2):

There’s another ore/food vendor near the souvenir shop in Liyue. Her name is Changshun.[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's also a vender under the port in Liyue. He's the guy you go to during one of Zhongli's quests for the Rite of Dissention.